# What's "think tank" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

What's [*think tank*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Think_tank) in Esperanto?

Literally *tank* means *akvujo*, so should it be *pensakvujo*? Does it make sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vikipedio donas la vorton ***pensfabriko***, kiu konservas la familiarecon de la angla. Alie, vi povas uzi ***publikafera instituto*** aŭ ***ŝtatafera fondaĵo*** ktp.

Origine, *think tank* (laŭlitere, penso-cisterno) estis ŝerca esprimo pri la homa cerbo.

En la 1950-aj jaroj, oni komencis uzi ĝin por la "cerbo" de organizaĵo—ekzemple, fako, aŭ duone sendependa instituto, kiu studas la detalojn de organiza plano.

Nuntempe, ĝi signifas: instituton por esploroj subtenantaj la ideojn de politika partio aŭ grupo.

Comment: This is Wikipedia on the origin of the term: _During the Second World War, think tanks were often referred to as "brain boxes" after the slang term for skull. The phrase "think tank" in wartime American slang referred to rooms where strategists discussed war planning. Later the term "think tank" was used to refer to organizations that offered military advice_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Think_tank

Comment: dankon pro via helpo! do cxu eblus krei "cerbumaro"?

Comment: *Cerbumi* signifas "pensi pene", kaj *cerbumo* signifas la rezultan penson, do *cerbumaro* estas "kolekto de diversaj, malfacile ellaboritaj pensoj." Eble vi celas ***cerbumantaro***, aro de homoj kiuj cerbumas. Tamen, aro ne ĉiam estas teamo.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the idea of *tank* transfers easily into other languages: it's not really got anything to do with a literal tank.

A think tank also hasn't got much to do with thinking itself, but instead with policy research and advocacy. So a different word might be better altogether, perhaps something like *politikesploraro*: "group of policy researchers". Or *planinstituto*: "policy institute".

Undoubtedly there will be better suggestions! My main point is that literal translations are usually not a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

From Google:

> a body of experts providing advice and ideas on specific political or economic problems.

Sperta Konsilistaro